# Jmeter BSF shel l: Response message: org.apache.bsf.BSFException: unable to load language: java

Tags: performance, jmeter

I want to  run java code in jmeter using BSF shell but it shows an error:

```
"Response message: org.apache.bsf.BSFException: unable to load language: java".
```

Please provide url where I can download java language jar for jmeter.

Answer (score 3):

1. **Easy way:** switch to [Beanshell Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting), Beanshell is quite Java-compliant (apart from modern features like generics, switch statement on strings, etc.
2. **Hard way:** patch *bsf-2.4.0.jar* file (lives under /lib folder of your JMeter installation) to add [JavaEngine](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.apache.bsf/com.springsource.org.apache.bsf/2.4.0/org/apache/bsf/engines/java/JavaEngine.java?av=f) class to it.
3. **Right way:**

   From [BSF Sampler Documentation](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BSF_Sampler):

   > The BSF API has been largely superseded by JSR-223, which is included in Java 6 onwards. Most scripting languages now include support for JSR-223; please use the JSR223 Sampler instead. The BSF Sampler should only be needed for supporting legacy languages/test scripts.

   So consider using [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Groovy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groovy_(programming_language)) language instead. In 99% of cases valid Groovy code will be valid Java code so it's unlikely that you'll have to change anything. See [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](https://blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) guide for details.